# Access-Control-Request-Header: - x-requested-with

Tags: javascript, http, cross-domain, cors, access-control

I am building a widget for my users and trying to get it working however I keep running into a X-Domain issue with this header. httpfox gives me - NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI - and on further investigation I find that its

```
Access-Control-Request-Method:  GET
Access-Control-Request-Header:  x-requested-with
```

I am not sure why its not loading but I basically call a script and then I am trying to grab some html to load it but it gets blocked with the above headers.

How can I get around this prob ?

Answer (score 5):

It's `Access-Control-Request-Headers` with "**`s`**"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Request-Headers